# What is the best way to update maven build number in Concourse pipeline?

Tags: maven, semantic-versioning, concourse

I have a spring boot app which is built to PCF with Concourse. I want to be able bump the pom build version number during the build.

I'd like to use a version file and the semver resource, however once I have the version number how can I pass the value to my maven command?

E.g.

```
package -Dbuild.version=version
```

How can I pass this version between tasks,  to my build task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `semver` resource, as explained in the [Concourse tutorial](https://concoursetutorial.com/miscellaneous/versions-and-buildnumbers/), writes the current version in file `RESOURCE_NAME/number`.

So assuming that your `semver` resource is named `version`, and that the job does a `get: version`, and that the task has `version` among its inputs, then your "package" command can be written as follows:

```
package -Dbuild.version=$(cat version/number)
```

I suggest to read the [Concourse tutorial](https://concoursetutorial.com/miscellaneous/versions-and-buildnumbers/), it is very good and will get you started :-)